# highcharts legend position wrong when align ='left' or 'right'?

Tags: highcharts

my jsfiddle sample is here. The vertical align is bottom. When I set align = 'center', the legend is underneath the charting area. However, if I set align='left' or 'right', the legend will occupy the charting area's space and make the area really small.
I want the legend at bottom left of the charting area, is it possible?

http://jsfiddle.net/daxu/xeb3n/585/

```
legend: {
        enabled: true,
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        y: 0,
        padding: 0,
        margin:5,
        itemMarginTop: 0,
        itemMarginBottom: 0,
        itemStyle:{
            fontSize: '10px'
            }
    },
```

Comment: You can set floating as true and verticalAlign as middle. http://jsfiddle.net/xeb3n/588/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `floating: true`, and then adjust `x` and `y` to get to the position that you want.

[Documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.floating)

Comment: this is not going to work, as how can I know which y to set? I do not want the legend to be in the chart area.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Set y to some value so it doesn't over lap the chart. Like this here: http://jsfiddle.net/xeb3n/587/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `floating` the position, you can use `x` when `align: 'center'`. In that case, the legend will be offset from the naturally aligned position.  Of course, you'll need to determine the offset to works best for your chart.  Negative `x` values will move the legend towards the left, see example image.

[image: Moving position to left, bottom corner of chart]